# Birt Chart toolTip show 2 toolTip on mouse hover

Tags: birt

I am using birt chart tool to display a chart. It's working properly. I have set a tool tip to a line chart. It shows the value correctly but while hovering it shows 2 popups.

Is it possible to set the tooltip position. What is the problem with the tooltip?

Thanks

Comment: were you able to get this to work ? I am in the same boat :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think it is only a problem for SVG charts. I suppose the problem is that the tooltip appears as a link to the browser. So when hovering the marker, the SVG-internal action listener displays an SVG version of the tooltip and the browser displays the tooltip again because the browser interprets it as it would be an html link with an "alt" attribute.
In another post (sorry, don't remember where) it was stated that this problem can be solved by upgrading the browser's SVG plugin, i.e. the Adobe SVG Plugin or something similar. But that's very odd, because it lets the choice to the user instead of solving the problem on the 'server side'...
Clearly it is something which should be fixed by BIRT contributors.

Answer (score 0):

I am running BIRT 4.2.1 and my graphs are in SVG and not seeing the issue.  What BIRT versions used is not listed for those reporting the problem.

I don't find a bug listed

```
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance%20desc&bug_status=__open__&product=BIRT&content=SVG%20tooltip&list_id=4816359
```

Presumably updating your BIRT version would solve the problem.